# How to force a textbox to update its text

Tags: c#, textbox, sendmessage, user32, spy++

So I've looked through maybe five to ten questions on stackoverflow about setting text into a textbox using a range of commands. I've tried SetWindowText, SendMessage with EM_SETSEL and EM_REPLACESEL, and a few others that I can't think of off the top of my head. For the most part I have been successful, except for one strange occurrence.

When I set the text of this specific text box, nothing appears, nothing changes. At first I thought I was not setting the data correctly. However, when I use Spy++ or Winspector to see the text of a textbox, the correct data with my changes are in there, but not displayed on the actual textbox. Even stranger, when I click back into the form with the textbox I "edited", spy++ and Winspector's data changes to what the textbox is displaying.

I spoke with a friend of mine and he mentioned it might be a race condition. I'm trying to edit this box and the textbox is being edited by some other thread as well.

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Edit: Alright so I did some more digging into what is causing the problem with the text changing back. I opened up Winspector and had it watch the textbox. From there I was able to identify the messages sent to the window between the final time the text data is correct, to the first time it changes. I also exported the results to an xml document with the parameters, but it is about 680 lines long.

Heres the list of messages: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW09t.png

Comment: Have you tried calling `InvalidateRect` on the control? It may just need to be re-drawn.

Answer (score 0):

The control may just need to re-paint itself.

You can try two API's to do that:

- [InvalidateRect - PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.invalidaterect)
- [RedrawWindow - PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.redrawwindow)

Comment: I have tried using InvalidateRect, wasn't able to get anything. I just tried to do RedrawWindow and nothing changed as well. I believe I used it correctly,

RedrawWindow(refBox, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RedrawWindowFlags.AllChildren);